# What is the lowest reasonable density for a Super Earth with earthlike living conditions?

Tags: planets, earth-like, gravity

A large planet roughly 3-4 times the mass of Earth. Trying to keep Gravity between 0.75G-1.25G for Earth-like Conditions.

I've looked into certain materials such as Silicon Carbide, which is reasonably light and mostly incompressible. Which is rare on Earth, yet common in space. Could a planet form with a large mass of Silicon Carbide without having the downsides of being a Carbon world? (I.e lack of water on the surface)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: In my simulator best candidate of earth-like planet of 3.6 earth masses has 1,69 earth's G and quite dense atmosphere of 2.4 of earth's (but this is second derivative parameter). The planet has enough metals to be not pure rocky one, so there's a magnetic field, water and so on. Don't know the compound but it's all based on meticulous physical formulas. The density 6.3 - I struggle to generate below 5.5 g/cm3 - don't remember why, but it was due to some gravity infridgements. Hope this help a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this is possible *(albeit quite unlikely)*, a silicon carbide world may not be habitable to life *(as we know it)*. According to [this paper](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.3847/PSJ/abaa3e), a lot of CH4 and H2 would be produced in the presence of water in the crust, hence likely forming a thick and dense atmosphere of reducing gases. So **definitely not earth-like.** However, if the temperatures and pressures are right, you could potentially have lakes of liquid methane and maybe have life based of different biochemistry *(think of methane or silicon based life)*, and maybe have a cool looking shiny diamond planet!

Comment: This is very helpful!

Potentially to make things more Earth-like perhaps some Microorganism could consume the Methane, and if over a long enough timescale enough Silicon Carbide is converted to Diamond the planet could become similar to Earth on the surface, while retaining a low density.